# Selectlist not working on IE8 specific

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-selectors, html-select

Why the following doesn't work on IE8 while it works on the all other browsers.

```
$(function () {

        //add binding to dropdowns
        $("#PersonsId").change(function () {
            $('option:selected', this).attr('selected', true).siblings().removeAttr('selected');
            //set value on hidden text field           
            if ($(this)[0].selectedIndex > 0) {                    
                $(this).parent().next().val($(this).find("option:selected").text());
            }
            else {
                $(this).parent().next().val("");
            }
        });
    });
```

Maybe this isn't the best solution so i'm asking how would you change this?

Comment: `$('option:selected', this).attr('selected', true).siblings().removeAttr('selected');` ? Why? What are you trying to achieve? When an option is selected it's siblings are unselected by default!

Comment: Thanks, in the mean time i've used http://www.browserstack.com to get to the bottom of the problem. Post this as an answer so i can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
 $('option:selected', this).attr('selected', true).siblings().removeAttr('selected');
```

is not needed because when you select the option the rest of the options is unselected by default. For setting the value to hidden field use the following code

$("input[type='hidden']").val($(this).val());